# mysql query to return true if all status for a particular id field is true

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a db table with more than one rows for a same ID  filed, with another field STATUS (may be 1 or 0). I want to get the status as 1 if all the STATUS is 1 for a particular ID else 0 if any one STATUS is 0(zero)

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: you *could* use a product and group result by id.

Comment: can you share screen shot of you table

Comment: Hi RC,
Your logic is correct, but how can i use product? there is no product function like SUM() in mysql/sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function:

- For a particular `ID`:

  ```sql
  SELECT MIN(STATUS) FROM my_table WHERE ID = ?
  ```
- For all `ID`:

  ```sql
  SELECT ID, MIN(STATUS) FROM my_table GROUP BY ID
  ```

Comment: hi eggyal,
MIN always give minimum value. I need the 1 , if all status value is 1 for a particular ID.
Above RC suggested to use product.. but how can? is it possible in single query?

Comment: @SHIN: `MIN()` will indeed always give the minimum value.  If any of the values are `0`, then `0` is the minimum; only if they are all `1` will `1` be the minimum.  This is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you Eggyal. Good logic.